# Android Widget with ImageView is Invisible Until I Start Moving It

Tags: java, android, widget

I've got a widget with an `ImageView`, whose source I'm setting with a URI to an image on the user's device. I set it with `RemoteViews.setImageViewUri()` in the `onUpdate` of the widget's provider. The strangest thing is happening: I can't see the widget or the image while the widget is stationary on my home screen, but when I pick it up and start moving it, the image appears!

Here are some screen shots illustrating this:

[image]
[image]

Here's the layout for the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/picture_widget_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/the_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        updateAllWidgets(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    private void updateAllWidgets(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        PuppyFramePersistenceManager persistenceManager = new PuppyFramePersistenceManager(context);

        for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.puppyframe_widget);
            Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, AlbumsActivity.class);

            Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("pw" + i + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
            configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

            PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.picture_widget_parent, configPendingIntent);

            String currentAlbumId = persistenceManager.getCurrentAlbumIdForAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
            if(currentAlbumId != null) {
                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(persistenceManager.getAlbumWithId(currentAlbumId).getImagePaths().get(0));
                remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.the_picture, imageUri);
            }

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.boztalay.puppyframe"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="com.boztalay.puppyframe.configuration.albums.AlbumsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.boztalay.puppyframe.configuration.editalbum.EditAlbumActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="com.boztalay.puppyframe.widget.PuppyFrameWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/puppyframe_info" />
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.boztalay.puppyframe.widget.ScreenOnService"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And lastly, this is my widget provider info:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="40dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="21600000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/puppyframe_widget"
    android:configure="com.boztalay.puppyframe.configuration.albums.AlbumsActivity"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you use onEnabled() instead of onUpdate() to initialize your widget ? I'm absolutely not sure.

Comment: If a user creates multiple instances of your widget, onEnabled() only gets called when the first widget is placed. I have my configuration activity updating the widgets so they get at least one onUpdate().

Comment: Have you tried calling the same `updateAllWidgets` method on `onEnabled` too?

Comment: could You provide your Manifest.xml and xml widgetProviderInfo xml file? While moving, your widget could show preview image, and when placed - some issue with update could occur.

Comment: I haven't tried doing that in onEnabled, but this happens with any image. However, I'll post my manifest and widget provider info in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ultimately has to do with the size of the images. With the very large images that the phone's camera takes, it would cause this bug. But with smaller ones on the phone, they appeared just fine. What I had to do was actually resize and cache the images that are too big, which I deemed to be 75% of the phone's screen's resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `AppWidgetManager` interacts with your `AppWidgetProvider` is not as documented. The documentation claims that if you have a configure activity, `onUpdate` is not called.

In fact, `onUpdate` is called before the configure activity starts. It's not called when the activity finishes. Looking at your `onUpdate`, it appears that if the appwidget isn't configured yet, it leaves the `ImageView` blank. Even without seeing your configure activity, I guess that what's going on is this:

- `AppWidgetManager` creates the new widget and calls `onUpdate`. Because the new widget is not yet configured, you don't set the `ImageView` to an image.
- The configure activity runs and sets `RESULT_OK`. The widget is now configured, but hasn't been updated again, so the `ImageView` is still blank.
- When you resize or move the widget, the `AppWidgetManager` calls `onUpdate` again. This time, your code reads the widget configuration and sets the `ImageView`. Now the widget shows the chosen image.

The answer is that when your configure activity finishes, it should send an intent to your `AppWidgetProvider` to have it update again. This isn't a panacea, though, as there are other bugs in `AppWidgetProvider`. For example, if you do an orientation change while the configure activity is running, restarting it, the `AppWidgetProvider` hides the appwidget from the screen, even after you finish and return `RESULT_OK`. Changing the orientation again while the launcher is showing (after the configure activity has finished) makes the appwidget appear.

The reason I know all this is that I've had the same problems writing a similar app, which may be helpful to you if you're struggling with this functionality. **Showr** displays images on the home screen or lock screen. The images can be chosen from other apps on the device (such as the Gallery), downloaded from a URL, or updated from an RSS or Atom feed. It even scales the images to an appropriate size and can crop them to fit the appwidget. It's a [free download from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr).

Comment: I would agree with you on this, but when I let the widget go again after moving or resizing, it disappears again. In my configuration activity, I'm definitely updating the widget. I set a breakpoint and used some logging statements in onUpdate to be sure. Thanks for the help, though, I didn't know that about orientation changes.